# Shifting only 1 bit in an integer by a specific number of places

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitboard

I am creating a chess program and for the board representation I am using bitboards. The bitboard for white pawns looks like this:

`whitePawns=0x000000000000FF00;`

Now, if I want to move the white pawn on the square D4, I would have to shift the 12th bit by either 8 or 10 places so that it can get on to the next rank. I want to shift the 12th bit without disturbing the positions of the remaining bits. How do I do that?

After shifting the whitePawns variable should look this:

`whitePawns=0x0000000008F700;`

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving a bit within a byte using bitfield or bitwise operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431107/moving-a-bit-within-a-byte-using-bitfield-or-bitwise-operators)

Comment: I want to shift a single bit within an integer without disturbing other bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't want a shift, you want to swap to bits. Try turning bit A off and then turning bit B on. Something like this:

```
whitePawns &= ~(1 << A); // Turn bit A off
whitePawns |= (1 << B);  // Turn bit B on
```

Where A and B are the positions of the bits you want to swap.

**EDIT:** Whether the move is valid or not is another story, make the move only if bit B is NOT set (and probably other conditions):

```
if (!(whitePawns & (1 << B))) {
    // Make the swap.
}
```

Comment: This solution partially approaches what I have in mind. What if the bit I want to move my pawn to, is set? In that case I cannot swap. I just want to shift a bit in position to A to position B. It has to overwrite the value of bit B. Whatever be its value.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than shifting the bit, you can remove `1` from the old position, and put it in the new position.

For example, if you know that the bit at position 5 is set, and the bit at position 12 is not set, and you want to shift the fifth bit to the 12-th position, you can do it with a single XOR:

```
whitePawns ^= ((1 << 5) | (1 << 12));
```

The way this works is that XOR-ing a value with a mask "flips" all bits of the value marked by 1s in the mask. In this case, the mask is constructed to have 1s in positions 5 and 12. When you XOR it with the positions, the 1 in fifth position becomes zero, and zero in the 12-th position becomes 1.

Comment: Will this work if the bit at position 12 is set? What will be the modification in that case?

Comment: @RohitShinde If the bit at position 12 is set, this will not work, because `XOR` flips bits marked by 1s. If you want to reset a bit to zero, use `v &= ~(1<<i)`. To set a bit unconditionally, use `v |= (1<<i)`. The reason I thought that XOR would work nicely is that a piece cannot replace a piece of the same color in chess.